# Why am I getting 404 error in python , blueprint?

Tags: python, flask, blueprint

I defined a blueprint route like this:

```
@mod_patient_directory.route('/delete-patient/<string:doc_id>',  methods = ['GET'])
def delete_record(self, doc_id):
    mongo.db.patient.remove({'_id': doc_id})
    return redirect(url_for('main-page'))
```

And on the form I called the method that is:

```
 <form action="{{ url_for('patient_directory.delete_record',doc_id= doc_id )}}" method="post">
                              <input type="hidden" name="docId" id="docId" value="{{ patient_doc._id }}" />
                              <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="delete" />
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                              </button>
 </form>
```

Can anybody tell me why I'm getting a 404 error?

Comment: How did you register your blueprint with the app?

Comment: @Makoto :  app.register_blueprint(mod_patient_directory)

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you have `methods = ['GET']` on the route, but `method="post"` on the form tag. You should not use `GET` for dangerous actions like deleting records, so you should change the `methods` accepted to `['POST']`.

As @Makoto pointed out that will give you a 405 error, but you are getting a 404 error, so there must be another problem. You've posted how you're registering the blueprint, but where within your code are you doing that? One thing to be careful of with blueprints is that you need to register all of the routes before you register the blueprint.

Comment: I'd expect that to produce a 405 Not Allowed, but not a 404.  The latter implies that *the resource doesn't even exist* to begin with.

Comment: Also, if we're talking DELETE, we should be just sending a DELETE to the server instead.  Using GET or POST has different connotations.